# std::vector<Bar> as a member variable in class Foo needs an empty constructor for Bar

Tags: c++, class, vector, enums, nested-class

Here is the situation :

I have a class defined by the following files.

Foo.h file :

```
template<typename MyType>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int number = 50);

private:
    typedef enum {VAR1, VAR2} Type;

    class Bar
    {
        MyType a;
        Type b;

        Bar(int param1, Type param2) : a(param1), b(param2) {}
    }

    std::vector<Bar> vec;
};
```

Foo.cpp file :

```
template<typename MyType>
Foo::Foo(int number) : vec(number)
{ }
```

The problem is when I compile this, I get an error in the first line of .cpp file saying that it needs a constructor for Bar with no arguments. I guess it needs it to create the vector in Foo. I added a constructor with no arguments for Bar giving the following .h file :

```
template<typename MyType>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int number = 50);

private:
    typedef enum {VAR1, VAR2} Type;

    class Bar
    {
        MyType a;
        Type b;

        Bar() {}   // <----  Line added
        Bar(int param1, Type param2) : a(param1), b(param2) {}
    }

    std::vector<Bar> vec;
};
```

Now I can compile and it works, but there is a warning at the line I just added saying that `Member 'b' was no initialized in this constructor`. Problem with enum, maybe?

I don't understand what I should do in order to get it to work without having this warning.

**Edit** : I received some answers saying to add an initialization list to the empty constructor. However, my class is in fact a template class and `a` is an unknown type to me, so I can not initialized it as I don't know its type. I tried initializing only `b` in the initialization list in Bar and it worked. The warning disappeared, but is it okay to let `a` uninitialized? Would there be a way to remove the constructor with no argument of Bar and still give a size to the vector in the constructor of Foo?

Comment: Primitive types, like `int` and `enum`, are left uninitialized by default. Non-primitive types, like `struct foo{int a;}` have their nullary constructor called (in the above `foo` case the implicit nullary constructor does nothing because `int` is a primitive type and by default left uninitialized). The warning is saying that you have a primitive type instance that is being left uninitialized by your constructor.  If `a` is not a primitive type, `Bar():b(VAR1){}` is equivalent to `Bar():a(),b(VAR1){}` -- if it is a primitive type, then it is uninitialized.  In short, use `Bar():a(),b(VAR1){}`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the initializer list in the definition of `Foo::Foo(int)`. You're writing

```
Foo::Foo(int n)
    : vec(n) { }
```

i.e. you're using the constructor

```
std::vector<Bar>::vector(size_t number, const Bar &x = Bar())
```

Please note that `x = Bar()` which means you fill the vector with standard constructed instances of `Bar`. Since there's at least one constructor defined in `Bar` the compiler does not automatically provide the standard constructor.

Define a standard constructor in `Bar` like the other answers suggest or put something else in the constructor of `Foo`, for example this

```
Foo::Foo(int n)
    : vec(n, Bar(1, VAR1)) { }
```

and the compiler error vanishes.

**Answer to your edit**: The warning you receive probably means: The member `a` isn't proper initialized. Since it's an `int` this might be okay (C++ does not force you to initialize `int`s). But beware of strange and arbitrary values in the member `a` later in your program. A better solution is to set it at construction time to a well-defind state which means to you "this value is unknown."

**Edit**: I deleted all the stuff I wrote about heterogeneous containers. However if you need these things take a look at the edit history of my post.

You can initialize `a` in the standard constructor of `Bar` like this:

```
Bar::Bar() : a(MyType()), b(UNKNOWN) { }
```

and by adding `UNKNOWN` to the enumeration `Type`. This assumes the type `MyType` is standard constructible. This applies for example to all primitive type like `int`, `double`, etc. This gives you a well defined state of the `Bar` object which could mean to you *unknown*. It can be tested by comparing `b` to `UNKNOWN`.

As yakk stated in his comment: Primitive types like enumerations can be left unitialized but in your case the compiler warns you: It may be your member `b` contains a value which has no label like `VAR1` or `VAR2` at all. It is always a good idea to initialize all members with well-defined values unless you're really forced to not to do so - for example if execution is bloody crucial.

Comment: I edited my question. I can't give a value of 1 to `a` like you did in your answer because it is an unknown type to me.

Comment: It should be noted similar logic will be required for any `.resize()` request. If activities such as this are frequent the OP may be better off just defining default values for the parameterized constructor in the `Bar` definition: `Bar(int param1=1, Type param2=VAR1) : a(param1), b(param2) {}`

Comment: @Gradient: You means at the construction of `Foo` you don't know the conrete value of `a` in `Bar`? In this case I suggest to handle this kind of unknown state in `Bar` internally by setting it to a specific value (like `0`). This may be done via a standard constructor for `Bar`.

Comment: No, I really don't know the type of `a`. It is in fact a template class. I corrected it in an edit to my question.

Comment: I don't want to store heteregeneous things in the vector. If the user of my class wants to store Int in it, he calls Foo<Int> myFoo;. If he wants to store CustumOjb in it, he calls Foo<CustumObj> myFoo.

Comment: In an instance of Foo, there is only one type in the vector. I reedited my question to add the `template ...` lines for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an initialization list to the empty constructor (and probably make it public).

```
class Bar
{
    int a;
    Type b;

    Bar() : a(0), b(VAR1) {}   // initialize the members to default values.
    Bar(int param1, Type param2) : a(param1), b(param2) {}
}
```